# Room blocking using these table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, mysqli

I have these following database tables

**reservation tbl**

```
.---------------+-----------------+------------------+---------------.
| reservationID |    guestID      |     check_in     |   check_out   |
+---------------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+
|       1       |       1         |     2016-02-13   |  2016-02-14   |
|       2       |       1         |     2016-02-16   |  2016-02-19   |
.---------------+-----------------+------------------+---------------.
```

**roomreservation tbl**

```
.---------------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------.
| roomReserveID | reservationID   |  date_scheduled  | roomDetailsNo |   roomNo     |
+---------------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+
|       1       |       1         |     2016-02-13   |      2        |      101     |
|       2       |       1         |     2016-02-13   |      2        |      101     |
|       3       |       4         |     2016-02-16   |      6        |      116     |
|       4       |       4         |     2016-02-17   |      6        |      116     |
|       5       |       4         |     2016-02-18   |      6        |      116     |
|       6       |       4         |     2016-02-19   |      6        |      116     |
.---------------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------.
```

**rooms tbl**

```
.---------+-----------------+-----------.
| RoomID  | RoomDetailsNo   |room_status| 
+---------+-----------------+-----------+
|   101   |         1       | reserved  |
|   102   |         3       | available |
|   103   |         3       | available |
|   104   |         2       | reserved  |
|   105   |         2       | available |
|   116   |         6       | reserved  |
.---------+-----------------+-----------.
```

**roomdetails tbl**

```
.----------------+----------------+---------.
| RoomDetailsNo  |   room_type    |room_rate|
+----------------+----------------+---------+
|        1       | Standard Room  |  3000   |
|        2       | Deluxe Room    |  3500   |
|        3       | Family Room    |  4000   |
|        4       | Standard Quad  |  4000   |
|        5       | Deluxe Quad    |  4000   |
|        6       | Dormitory Room |  4000   |
.----------------+----------------+---------.
```

and below I have the current query I am using to block the room 101 in 2016-02-13 to 2016-02-14 and room 116 in 2016-02-16 to 2016-02-19.

```
$roomBlock = mysqli_query($conn, "
SELECT COUNT(r.roomDetailsNo) AS available_rooms, rd.roomDetailsNo, rd.room_type, rd.room_rate,

    r.room_status, rd.room_pax, rd.max_cap, rd.inclusive, rd.description, rd.image_name
    FROM rooms AS r
    LEFT JOIN roomdetails AS rd
    ON r.roomDetailsNo = rd.roomDetailsNo
    WHERE r.roomNo  = (SELECT rr.roomNo
                        FROM roomreservation AS rr
                        WHERE rr.date_scheduled NOT BETWEEN '$newCheckIn' AND '$newCheckOut')
    GROUP BY room_type;
") OR die("Error in roomBlocking:".mysqli_error($conn));
```

variables $newCheckIn and $newCheckOut came from user which are their desired check-in and check-out date. how do I not display the rooms that are reserved in certain dates based roomreservation?

When I tried this query the result was:
Error in roomBlocking: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: exactly as the error says - you're trying to use a subquery in a context where only ONE value is allowed to be returned, but the subquery returns MULTIPLE rows. In other words, don't use `=`, use `IN`

Comment: So what should be the right query to remove unavailable rooms inside dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery is returning more than 1 result which is expected so you should use where r.roomNo in, instesd of where r.roomNo =